# PDF reader which supports additional "local" bookmarks

Tags: windows-7, pdf-reader

What I mean? As I often read several PDF books at a time, usually non-related, it would help greatly if I could place a bookmark or two marking where I left last time, or where I found some interesting note I wish to come back later.

"local" means that it would be great if those could be made in some custom folder, without actually modifying the PDF file itself. So, more of a set of files with info about the PDF file, and then data with location, some note and whatever.

Does anyone know of any PDF reader which comes close to having something like that?